# SQL query from C#

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to query SQL Server database from C#

I have class

```
Class_A 
{
  public fetch((string name, string last_name))
  {
    SqlConnection conn = null;
    double val = 0;
    string server = "123.444.22.sss";
    string dbase = "xyz";
    string userid = "cnsk";
    string password = "xxxxxx";
    string connection = "Data Source=" + server + ";Initial Catalog=" + dbase 
                        + ";User ID=" + userid + ";Password=" + password;

    conn = new SqlConnection(connection);

    try
    {
      conn.Open();
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
      string e = "Database error contact administrator";
      MessageBox.Show(e, "Error!");
    }
    try
    {
      SqlDataReader myReader = null;
      SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from table where NAME"
         + " = name and LAST_NAME = last_name", conn);
      myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
      while (myReader.Read())
      {
        //do something

      }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
    return (0);
  }
}
```

There is a problem in my query.

When I give normal query "select * from table" ---  this gives me perfect results.

But when I try to give where condition it gives me error. Any suggestions, to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: This is prone to SQL injection. Don't forget to sanitize your data before inserting it in a query.

Comment: Based on the answers provided by the others I would have come up with this: `SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(String.Format("select * from table where NAME = '{0}' and LAST_NAME = '{1}'", name, last_name), conn);`

Comment: @Silvermind that is very open to sql injections http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: @ErikPhilips, I agree. +1 to indicate that your comment matters. I'm more a Linq2Entities guy, so I don't suffer from these problems ;).

Comment: @Silvermind I am too, until I have to `update table set bitfield = 1 where somefield = somevalue...  43,563 rows affected`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ⚠️ **WARNING** This answer contains a SQL injection security vulnerability. Do not use it. Consider using a parameterized query instead, as described in some of the other answers to this question (e.g. Tony Hopkinson's answer).

Try adding quotes around the values in the where clause like this:

```
select * from table where NAME = 'name' and LAST_NAME = 'last_name'
```

In your case where you are using variables you need to add the quotes and then concatenate the  values of the variables into the string. Or you could use `String.Format` like this:

```
var sql = String.Format("select * from table where [NAME] = '{0}' and LAST_NAME = '{1}'", name, last_name);
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sql);
```

Comment: name and last_name are the variable names

Comment: also if you are going to use a reserved work its best to use square brackets [name] for example

Answer (score 9):

Use a parameterised query, and more usings, and stop with the generic exceptions.

something like this where somName and SomeLastName are the values that you wan t to query for.

```
String sql = "Select * From SomeTable Where [Name] = @Name and [Last_Name] = @LastName";
try
{
  using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
  {
    conn.Open();
    using( SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql,conn))
    {
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Name", DbType.String,someName));
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("LastName", DbType.String,someLastName));
      using(IDataReader myReader = command.ExecuteReader())
      {
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
           //do something
        }
      }
    }
  } 
  return 0; // Huh?
}
catch(SqlException sex)
{
   Console.Writeline(String.Format("Error - {0}\r\n{1}",sex.Message, sex.StackTace))
}
```

NB not checked might be a silly in it

Comment: +1 for `Using`, it is frighteningly uncommon on so many SO questions.   Take a look at `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dce36088.aspx as well (hidden gem people hardly use for some reason)

Comment: I know about that one, but rarely bother with it, has it's uses though. It's painful to me how often we shoot ourselves in the foot by being in too much of hurry to bother to aim as well.

Comment: Is the `using` block necessary for `SqlCommand`? The examples in the [documentation for that class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=netframework-4.8) do not rely on `using`. Other [Microsoft examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) on how to query an SQL server do not show it either.

Comment: @Ama  It implements IDisposable, so it could be necessary. Leaving it out gains you nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
select * from table where NAME = 'name' and LAST_NAME = 'last_name'
```

instead of

```
select * from table where NAME = name and LAST_NAME = last_name
```

Edit:

If `name` and `last_name` are your parameters then try this:

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from table where NAME = @name and LAST_NAME = @last_name", conn); 
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@name", name );
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@last_name", last_name );
```

Using parameterized commands means that you are invulnerable to a potential huge security hole - sql injection which **is** possible when command text is manually concatenated.

Answer (score 1):

The text needs to be quoted as others have said--but that's not really the right answer here.  Even without malice you're going to run into trouble with the Irish here, look what happens when you try to look for Mr. O'Neill.  Use parameters instead.