# SQl query into C#

Tags: c#, sql

I want to run a SQL query from C#.

Here's the query

```
strmyQuery = 
     SELECT DISTINCT UID = STUFF(
     (
        SELECT ';' + UID FROM USERS WHERE [urole] = 'support' 
          FOR XML PATH  ('')), 1, 1, ''
     )
     FROM USERS AS t
```

This query basically gives me a semicolon delimited list of `uid`'s from `USERS` table where it meets the condition defined in where clause.

I want to pass this query to a C# string variable `strmyQuery` and run it.

TIA.

Sorry for being unclear. What I was trying to do was create a web method that would return a dataset from he result of the query above. For some reasons its not returning me anything.
I could run the query in SQL and get resultset but not quite sure why the web method returns it blank.

here's my code and I found the issue in my code and rectified it to get the resultset I wanted. Thanks all for your I/p.

```
public DataSet Getu_ids()
     {
         string connectionString =
         ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDB"].ConnectionString;

         // Create a string variable for the modified SQL statement
       string strids = "";



         // Create a string variable for the default SQL statement
        strids = "SELECT DISTINCT UID = STUFF( "
        + "( "
        + "SELECT ';' + UID FROM USERS WHERE [urole] = 'Support' "
        + "FOR XML PATH  ('')), 1, 1, '' "
        + ") "
        + "FROM USERS AS t";

                      SqlConnection connUser = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
         SqlDataAdapter daUser = new SqlDataAdapter(strids , connUser);

         // Create a dataset object to store the data
        DataSet dsids = new DataSet();
         // Open the connection
        connUser.Open();
         // Fill the dataset
        daUser.Fill(dsids, "[USERS]");
         // Clean up
        connUser.Close();
        connUser = null;
         //here's the culprit
         dsids = null;

         return dsids;
     }
```

Comment: Google or Bing "sql data access c#" and follow some examples.

Comment: One-word difference: [SQL query from C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966301/sql-query-from-c-sharp?rq=1)

Comment: If we remove the tags from this question's title, I think we'd be left with "into."

Comment: Do you have a question? This is pretty basic stuff, there's LOADS of tutorials out there on this if you'd just look for them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string sql = "SELECT DISTINCT UID = STUFF( "
            + "( "
            + "SELECT ';' + UID FROM USERS WHERE [urole] = 'support' "
            + "FOR XML PATH  ('')), 1, 1, '' "
            + ") "
            + "FROM USERS AS t";

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
if (dr.HasRows)
{
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        // process data
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought he just wanted to know how to write the query to C# variable.