# How to insert just the date in sql using vb.net using a date time picker

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datepicker

i keep getting an error when i start the form saying "unable to convert mysql date/time value to system.datetime"

this is my code

```
Private Sub Add_Button1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Add_Button.Click
    MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MySqlConn.ConnectionString = "Server = Localhost; database = apartmentdb; user id = root; Password = "
    Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader

    Try
        MySqlConn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "Insert into Apartmentdb.Bookings(Apartment_ID, Client_ID, Booking_start_Date, Booking_end_Date, Total_Days, Price_per_Week, Total_Price) Values ('" & TextBox5.Text & "', '" & TextBox4.Text & "', '" & DateTimePicker4.Value & "' , '" & DateTimePicker3.Value & "' ,'" & TextBox3.Text & "', '" & TextBox2.Text & "', '" & TextBox1.Text & "')"
        Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)
        Reader = Command.ExecuteReader

        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")
        MySqlConn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MySqlConn.Dispose()

    End Try

    Call GridView_load()

End Sub
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966301/sql-query-from-c-sharp/9966451#9966451 Among other things you are open to sql injection attacks and converting dates to strings is just a bad idea. As is trapping that exception, waht is the user going to do with it. Oh and you don't need a reader.

Comment: ps i know the link is c#, but it's the .net stuff you need to pay attention to.

Comment: could you show me how you would edit the code?

Comment: don't worry you helped me a lot the problem fixed when I stopped converting it to string thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a VB guy but this should be a start.

```
Private Sub Add_Button1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Add_Button.Click
  Using MySqlConn as New MySqlConnection("Server = Localhost; database = apartmentdb; user id = root; Password = ")
    Dim Query As String
    Query = "Insert into Apartmentdb.Bookings(Apartment_ID, Client_ID, Booking_start_Date, Booking_end_Date, Total_Days, Price_per_Week, Total_Price) 
Values (@Apartment_ID,@Client_ID,@Start_Date,@End_Date,@Total_Days,@Price_Per_week, @Total_Price)"
    MySqlConn.Open()
    Using MyCommand = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)
      MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ApartmentID",TextBox5.Text)
      MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Client_ID", TextBox4.Text)
      // and so on.
      MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery
      MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")
    End Using
  End Using
  Call GridView_load()
End Sub
```

Note catching the exception is pointless unless this function does not matter at all. You should only trap exceptions you can handle.
Using removes the need for try finally, closing stuff. scopes everything inside it and it works very well with connection pooling.
Parameterised queries not only stop injection attacks, they are great for localised data, such as number and date formats.

Your problem is almost certainly when you code converted Picker.Value to a string it came out with a string your sql server did not know how to deal with. Even if it had got past that. You could get the old 8/6/2015 is 8th of June or 6th of August problem.
Stripping the time is a slightly different problem depends on your db, but if you want to make sure its 0 (midnight) then `SomePicker.Value.Date` will do the deed.

Comment: Any vb guys feel free to correct any sillies on my part.